# When using texture arrays, why do I not have to bind the sampler to the shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-4

I am creating an array of textures using `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` in my code:

```
// Load all images ito opengl
unsigned int width, height;
std::vector<unsigned char> textures;
int num = 0;
for ( auto each : image_list )
{
    // Load PNG
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer, this_texture;

    lodepng::load_file(buffer, each.string().c_str());
    auto lode_error = lodepng::decode(this_texture, width, height, buffer);
    if (lode_error)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("lodepng has reported this error: " + std::string(lodepng_error_text(lode_error)));
        return false;
    }
    m_indexes.insert(std::make_pair(each.filename().string(), num));
    textures.insert(textures.end(), this_texture.begin(), this_texture.end());
    num++;
}

// Active texture
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

// Generate texture
glGenTextures(1, &m_texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, m_texture_id);

// Send pixels
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             width, height,
             image_list.size(),
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             textures.data());

// Set options
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Here are the shaders I am using:

#### Vertex Shader

```
#version 430 core

/* layouts */
layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_vertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 in_uv;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 in_tint;
layout (location = 3) in mat4 in_model;
layout (location = 7) in vec3 in_scale;
layout (location = 8) in float in_textured_index;

/* uniforms */
uniform mat4 ortho;
uniform mat4 view;

/* outputs */
out vec4 tint;
out vec2 uv;
out float textured_index;

void main()
{
    mat4 mvp = ortho * view * in_model;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(in_vertex * in_scale, 1.0);
    tint = in_tint;
    uv = in_uv;
    textured_index = in_textured_index;
}
```

#### Fragment Shader

```
#version 430 core

/* inputs from vertex shader */
in vec4 tint;
in vec2 uv;
in float textured_index;

/* output to GPU */
out vec4 fragment;

/* texture sampler */
uniform sampler2DArray sampler_unit;


void main()
{
    fragment = texture(sampler_unit, vec3(uv.xy, textured_index)).rgba;
    fragment = fragment * tint;
}
```

#### Code to bind the texture array:

```
void ArrayTextures::attach()
{
    if (glIsTexture(m_texture_id)){
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, m_texture_id);
    }
}
```

What I have noticed, is that I do not have to attach the texture unit or the texture id to my shader, as long as the texture is bound with above function. It just works. I would like to understand why. In OpenGL 3.X, you have to bind the sampler to your shader before you can use it. Is there any automatism behind the scenes, that I am not aware of? Since I have a 5700XT, may this be an AMD specific oddity? What is the correct way here, so I can be sure it also works on NVIDIA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the sampler type. The binding between the texture object and the texture sampler is the texture unit. The texture object must be bound to a texture unit, and the texture unit number must be set to the texture sampler uniform.

In GLSL almost everything is initialized with 0 respectively 0.0 by default. Therefore the default [Binding point](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points) is 0. If the texture is bound to the texture unit 0 (`GL_Texture0`), it is not necessary to set the texture sampler uniform as it is 0 by default.

Comment: I have changed it to `GL_TEXTURE1` and it stopped working. Binding `1` to the shader made the textures display again. Thanks for the answer. Initialization just wasn't something I was looking at .